# Cannot get the method remove(position) in recycler view in contextual method

Tags: android, menu, android-recyclerview

I am trying to delete item when long clicked in contextual menu.I performed all the needed method but inside the context menu I could not see the option for remove in recycler view.

```
public class History extends AppCompatActivity {
public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public MRecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
      recyclerAdapter= new MRecyclerAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);



    }



    public  class MRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<History.ViewHolder>
    {


        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {   //creates and returns view holder

              View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.options_pin,null,false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder= new ViewHolder(v);


            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {   //all work done in onbind
 holder.textView.setText("done");
            registerForContextMenu(holder.linearLayout);



        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            return 5;  //count

        }
    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{   //holds all view maps
                    TextView textView;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            linearLayout=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        }





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemNumber=item.getItemId();
        switch (itemNumber)
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                break;






        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {


        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        MenuInflater menuInflater= getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_context,menu);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info= (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();


        switch (item.getItemId())
{




    case R.id.delete:
        Toast.makeText(History.this,"Delete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //delete task

//I want to delete the current item selected here



        break;
    case R.id.copy:
        Toast.makeText(History.this,"copy",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        //copy task

        break;

}

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When user clicks delete, I am trying to delete the items but I do not see remove there. i tried for both, recyclerView.remove and recyclerAdapter.remove

```
 case R.id.delete:
            Toast.makeText(History.this,"Delete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //delete task

    //I want to delete the current item selected here



            break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a method

```
public void remove(int position) {
    arrayList.remove(position);
}
```

Use

```
                            ((MRecyclerAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter()).remove(position);
```

to remove item. Short and sweet thnx.

Comment: yeah thnx I forgot that remove is our custom method

Answer (score 0):

Use pop up menu that is latest trending. This [link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/create-options-menu-recyclerview-item-tutorial/) will help you how to implement it

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int **position**) {
        MyList myList = list.get(position);
        holder.textViewHead.setText(myList.getHead());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(myList.getDesc());

        holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //creating a popup menu
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, holder.buttonViewOption);
                //inflating menu from xml resource
                popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu);
                //adding click listener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.menu1:
                                //handle menu1 click
                                break;
                            case R.id.menu2:
                                //handle menu2 click
                                break;
                            case R.id.menu3:
                                //handle menu3 click
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                //displaying the popup
                popup.show();

            }
        });
```